# R-program CompQuadForm/sum of squares of correlated normal variables.

Tags: statistics

I am trying to use the R-program to calculated sum of squares of two correlated normal variable with non-zero means. I have used the Imhof and Davies algorithme and they work well if means equals zero. If means are non-zero I can get the valid results. How  must the non-centrality parameter be specified ?

Comment: This could be asked on [stats.se].